# How to load directory of csv to hdfs as parquet

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, parquet

I have a local folder on linux with thousands of CSV files.

Each csv file is ~1mb.

The files share the same columns/format, and they are distinguished by the file name itself (i.e. xxx_1.csv, xxx_2.csv, xxx_3,csv etc)

Now, i want to load the directory into the HDFS, and to save it in parquet format.

What is the right way to do it in python (spark 2.3)?

1. What is the best way to load the whole directory?
2. What partitioning should I use? (is the file name should be the partition? or is it better to add the file name as a new column?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Spark already reads whole directories and can write that whole dataframe out in Parquet

```
df = spark.read.csv("file:///local_csv_dir")
df.write.parquet("hdfs:///other/dir")
```

read.csv even has access to filenames so I don't think you can partition by it that way.

You can add in the file names using `withColumn` and `input_file_name` functions, however, you'd ideally partition on a field in your data with a low cardinality (few unique values)

An arguably "better" way would be to put all CSV files into a large BZ2 archive, and just put that on HDFS. Then you can read that one file in parallel, and write to different formats, or process it directly, all within Hadoop

Comment: You can add the file name (using input_file_name() method) to the df. 

In that case, if I'll partition by file-name (I have thousands of CSV files), I will get thousands of folders. 

Is it logical to partition in that way?

Comment: You should only do any partitioning if you're later going to query based on that field with WHERE statements

Comment: cricket_007,When running spark-submit with master=yarn, it fails to find the local files (i.e. failed in spark.read.csv("file:///local_csv_dir")).
Is it possible to read the local files and use master=yarn?
Thanks

Comment: @Nir only if each file is distributed to all YARN NodeManagers... Otherwise, you can must pass `--files` along with Spark submit. That's why I mentioned first archiving that data, and uploading in one or more more, larger files